# Facebook FQL to Graph api unpublished posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, feed, posts

I'm trying to migrate from FQL to Graph api and I'm running into some issues while trying to fetch unpublished posts from a page as they're not showing up.

This is the FQL:

```
select description,actor_id,app_data,app_id,attachment,comment_info, created_time,feed_targeting,likes,message,permalink,post_id,privacy,share_count,source_id,targeting,type,updated_time,is_published,scheduled_publish_time 
 from stream where source_id="{page-id}" and (is_published=0 or is_published=1) 
 ORDER BY created_time 
DESC LIMIT 250
```

And this is what I have now:

```
{page-id}/feed?fields=id,is_published,scheduled_publish_time,from,description,message,picture,link,name,caption,icon,privacy,type,status_type,object_id,created_time,updated_time,feed_targeting,shares,likes.limit(1),comments.limit(1),attachments&limit=250
```

The result set from FQL return several post for which `is_published = false`, while none of them show up with the api call. Obviously, I'm using the same access token for both. I've tried adding some more fields, removing some fields, making the call only for the promotable posts, but no luck. Am I missing something?

EDITED

There's a bug reported on Facebook regarding this in case anyone wants to subscribe:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/277633459027605/

Answer (score 0):

It has been confirmed that this is a bug.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/277633459027605/